# How to turn array of vectors into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following list with arrays:

```
[array([2, 1, 4, 1]), array([2, 4, 4, 2]), array([2, 2, 4, 0])]
```

I would like to turn it into a dataframe with a title "Vectors" that looks like this:

```
   "1x4 Vectors"
0 [2, 1, 4, 1]
1 [2, 4, 4, 2]
3 [2, 2, 4, 0]
```

I tried using

```
pd.DataFrame(name_of_data_with_vectors, columns = "4x1 Vectors")
```

But, I get the following error:
    AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns

Comment: That is not an array of vectors, that is a list of arrays. I'm not sure wht you are trying to accomplish with a DataFrame of arrays, but likely, there is a better way.

Comment: I will edit this in a moment.

Comment: This is not how DataFrames are supposed to work. You are just making your job harder with this. Do not store numpy arrays inside DataFrame cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a `dict` for the constructor:

```
In [17]: data = [array([2, 1, 4, 1]), array([2, 4, 4, 2]), array([2, 2, 4, 0])]

In [18]: pd.DataFrame({'4x1 Vectors':data})
Out[18]:
    4x1 Vectors
0  [2, 1, 4, 1]
1  [2, 4, 4, 2]
2  [2, 2, 4, 0]
```

Note, `pandas` is not designed with the use-case of arrays as elements in mind. That is why the constructor is trying to interpret your data-argument as a `3x4` dataframe instead of a `3x1`

Alternatively, change the "shape" of your list and make your `columns` argument a sequence of lists:

```
In [21]: pd.DataFrame([[d] for d in data], columns=['4x1 vectors'])
Out[21]:
    4x1 vectors
0  [2, 1, 4, 1]
1  [2, 4, 4, 2]
2  [2, 2, 4, 0]
```

But I repeat: you almost certainly don't want to do this. `DataFrames` don't work well with arrays as elements.

Comment: So, to avoid the issue of DataFrame not liking the arrays, I should transform arrays into lists?

Comment: @IsaacA dataframes won't work well with lists either. It sounds like you done want a dataframe, but some other container.

Comment: Mhmm, what do you suggest?

Comment: @IsaacA I couldn't really say unless you elaborate on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [np.array([2, 1, 4, 1]), np.array([2, 4, 4, 2]), np.array([2, 2, 4, 0])]
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(arrays), columns = ['1x4 Vectors'])

print(df)

    1x4 Vectors
0  [2, 1, 4, 1]
1  [2, 4, 4, 2]
2  [2, 2, 4, 0]
```